# Fechando aplicativo que estão em segundo plano

Tags: android

Galera, como eu faço pra encerrar um aplicativo, não deixando ele em segundo plano mas sim acabando com o processo!

Comment: Há alguma razão em especial para você querer fazer isso? A filosofia do Android é deixar isso com ele.

Comment: Realizar um gerenciador de bateria,onde em alguns casos fecharia todos os apps abertos em um click, este app e para realizar testes.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities) resposta do SO em inglês, você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // a linha acima mata o processo
}
```

PS: Lá diz que isso não vai matar a tarefa na memória, mas mata o processo, então acho que serve